# Trouble configuring existing Tomcat6 and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu

I just got the Eclipse Java EE version and tried to configure Tomcat by going to the Window-->preferences-->Server

But when I went to "runtime environment" and gave it the location of the current tomcat directory, it didn't seem to recognize it and didn't let me go to next screen.

Did I do something wrong?  The problem is that there are still the red squigly lines in the import statements of servlet libraries.  Is there some correct way to refresh the page so I can ensure that Eclipse indeed does not recognize those libraries still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you're pointing to the real Tomcat root directory which contains the `/bin`, `/conf`, `/lib`, etc folders, not to a directory which contains just `apache-tomcat-7.0.11` or something.

Also pay attention to the error/warning message in top of the wizard, if any, right below the title.

Comment: by the way, do you know what is the correct way to rebuild/refresh the page to ensure that indeed the squiggly red lines would still appear?

Comment: I think what I was trying to see was how to test if I actually got Tomcat and Eclipse configured and working :)

Answer (score 2):

I have been experiencing similar problems recently, sometimes even Eclipse not listing Apache Tomcat 6.0 among available servers. The solution was go to eclipse's metadata directory:

```
your_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
```

And delete following files:

```
org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
```

Then restart Eclipse and try again, everything should work.
Hope this helps!

Comment: As per OP's question history he was upgrading from 3.3 non-EE to 3.6 EE. I can't imagine that his workspace's metadata would be littered with incorrect server prefs, let alone contain any of them.